# Jquery deferred issue (ajax then animation then callback)

Tags: jquery, callback, deferred

I've got to make AJAX call, do some stuff after that and become a callback when everythig is done.

I call getUsers() function and need to know when all steps inside this function are fineshed.

Nothing I try works...

```
function getUsers(userId){
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../getUsers.php",
        data: {userid: userId},
        success: function(output){
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            $(output.activeUsers).appendTo("#users");
            $(output.inactiveUsers).appendTo("#users_inactive");

            $('.user').each(function(index){
                $(this).animate({
                    'height':55+'px'
                })
            })
            $('.user').promise().done(function() {
                overlay.fadeOut('fast',function(){
                    dfd.resolve;
                    return dfd.promise();
                });
            });
        }
    })
}


$.when(
    getUsers()
).then(function(){
    alert('something')
})
```

what am I doing wrong

Comment: Use `complete:` for `$.ajax()`. That will fire when the request is finished. It does not matter if the request was a success or failed.

Comment: missing `return` in `getUsers`

Comment: Arun, there is return at the place where I need to make callback, or should it be on very end?  /  Spokey, I need a callback not after ajax, but after all stuff...

Comment: @Sobakinet not... that is from a callback method... you need to add ` return dfd.promise();` at the bottom of `getUsers `

Comment: `dfd.resolve();` - you need to invoke the resolve function

Comment: dfd.resolve() + dfd.promise() at very end made it work )) Thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems are noted in the comments

```
function getUsers(userId) {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../getUsers.php",
        data: {
            userid: userId
        },
        success: function (output) {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            $(output.activeUsers).appendTo("#users");
            $(output.inactiveUsers).appendTo("#users_inactive");

            $('.user').animate({
                'height': 55 + 'px'
            }).promise().done(function () {
                overlay.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    //need to invoke the resolve function
                    dfd.resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }).fail(function () {
        //need to reject the promise if ajax request fails
        dfd.reject();
    });
    //return the promise here
    return dfd.promise();
}


$.when(getUsers()).then(function () {
    alert('something')
})
```